# Ember Test: input focus

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I really don't understand the chain of events that's happening here. Trying to follow the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/testing/acceptance/) as well as possible. I have:

```
test('Tab focus', function(assert) { 
    visit('/demo/form');
    click('input[type=text]');
    andThen(function() {
        assert.equal(
            find('input[type=text]').css('borderTopColor'), 'rgb(0, 125, 164)', 'Text input has focus'
        );
    });
});
```

only to have it fail:
[image]

There are no transitions on the color change, and if I hit rerun, it DOES pass.

Comment: What happens if you test for focus using find('input[type=text]').is(":focus") ?

Comment: Both `find('input[type=text]').is(':focus')` and `find('input[type=text]:focus')` will NOT return the true/.length = 1 as expected.  :(

Comment: If you can set up an ember twiddle (https://ember-twiddle.com/) with the example, maybe a few of us can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

for anyone still looking for an answer - you have to trigger "focus" event manually in your test:

```
triggerEvent(<alement selector>, 'focus');
```

more info: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/testing/acceptance/#toc_asynchronous-helpers